# Contar registros en Query - ORACLE

Tags: oracle, sql

Tengo una consulta muy simple que no logro acomodar, anexo mi query:

```
SELECT
    PE.SCHD_ID AS OFERTA,
    PA.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPCION,
    PE.STUD_ID,
    PS.FNAME AS NOMBRE,
    PS.LNAME,
    PO.ORG_ID,
    PO.ORG_DESC,
    PF.ACCT_ID,
    PA.ACT_CPNT_ID,
    PA.TOTAL_LEARNING_COST as "Costo Oferta",
    PA.CLOSED_DATE,
    NULL AS PRORRATEO
FROM PA_ENROLL_SEAT         PE
INNER JOIN PA_SCHED         PA
    ON PE.SCHD_ID=PA.SCHD_ID
INNER JOIN PA_STUDENT       PS
    ON PS.STUD_ID=PE.STUD_ID
INNER JOIN PA_ORG           PO
    ON PO.ORG_ID=PS.ORG_ID
INNER JOIN PA_ORG_FIN_ACCT  PF
    ON PF.ORG_ID=PO.ORG_ID
WHERE PA.SCHD_ID='86010'
```

Ésta consulta al ejecutarla, me arroja 3 registros, lo cual está excelente, pero necesito que en el último campo el cual llamo como  `"NULL AS PRORRATEO"`, necesito que me cuente la cantidad de registros (3) entre el total de "Costo Oferta" que en esta caso es un costo de $20,000.

En teoría el campo de PRORRATEO requiero que me realice la división del total del costo oferta (20,000) entre la cantidad de registros que mando llamar en mi consulta (3)  y en dicho campo me pueda mostrar 6,666.66 lo equivalente a
 20,000 / 3.

HELP no soy muy buena en esto aún =(

Comment: Eso no lo deberia hacer el query, lo deberia hacer la vista donde queres mostrar eso

Comment: Nisiquiera con una sub consulta?

Comment: Como te dice Gonzalo, lo ideal es resolverlo desde la vista, desde la consulta se puede resolver pero es tal vez un gasto innecesario de recursos para la base de datos. Idealmente por SQL deberías insertar los datos en una temporal y a partir de esta, calcular el valor total, actualizar cada registro con el prorrateo y por último y muy importante, ajustar uno de los valores (si corresponde) para que el prorrateo sume el total.

Comment: Hola Patricio agradezco mucho tus comentarios, el tema es que estoy utlizando un reporteador llamado "plateau report designer" este se alimenta con SAP. el tema grandisimo es que en este, no puedo actualizar, insertar, eliminar, etc , solamente puedo hacer consultas, por dicho tema requeriría hacerlo en el query...

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener el `Costo Oferta` por `SCHD_ID` entiendo yo, lo más sencillo es hacer esto:

```
SELECT  SCHD_ID,
        SUM(TOTAL_LEARNING_COST) as "Total_Costo_Oferta",
        FROM PA_SCHED
        WHERE SCHD_ID = '86010'
        GROUP BY SCHD_ID
```

Si quitamos el `WHERE`, te permitiría hacer una consulta más amplia si hiciera falta. Este total puede incorporarse a tu consulta para llegar a un prorateo rudimentario:

```
SELECT  PE.SCHD_ID AS OFERTA,
        PA.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPCION,
        PE.STUD_ID,
        PS.FNAME AS NOMBRE,
        PS.LNAME,
        PO.ORG_ID,
        PO.ORG_DESC,
        PF.ACCT_ID,
        PA.ACT_CPNT_ID,
        PA.TOTAL_LEARNING_COST as "Costo Oferta",
        PA.CLOSED_DATE,
        T.Total_Costo_Oferta / PA.TOTAL_LEARNING_COST as 'PRORRATEO'
        FROM PA_ENROLL_SEAT PE
        INNER JOIN PA_SCHED PA
            ON PE.SCHD_ID=PA.SCHD_ID
        INNER JOIN PA_STUDENT PS
            ON PS.STUD_ID=PE.STUD_ID
        INNER JOIN PA_ORG PO
            ON PO.ORG_ID=PS.ORG_ID
        INNER JOIN PA_ORG_FIN_ACCT  PF
            ON PF.ORG_ID=PO.ORG_ID
        INNER JOIN (
             SELECT  SCHD_ID,
                     SUM(TOTAL_LEARNING_COST) as "Total_Costo_Oferta",
                     FROM PA_SCHED
                     WHERE SCHD_ID = '86010'
                     GROUP BY SCHD_ID
           ) T
           ON T.SCHD_ID = PA.SCHD_ID
        WHERE PA.SCHD_ID = '86010'
```

Digo un prorrateo rudimentario, por que tienes un problema con los decimales períodicos o infinitos, dónde por mas precisión que le des a la variable, la suma de los prorrateos no te dará exactamente 1. Habitualmente lo que se suele hacer, si tuvieras la posibilidad de usar una tabla intermedia, es ajustar el valor más alto para que la suma total de 1.